# Is there a way to setup code completion trigger in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

By default IntelliJ IDEA gives code suggestions almost whenever I type. Is there a way to set specific triggers, like only show suggestions when I typed dot or uppercase letters (like in Eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, disable the **Autopopup code completion** option:

[image: autopopup]

Then use the [keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/auto-completing-code.html) depending on the completion type you need. Shortcuts can be changed in `Settings` | `Keymap`.

[image: shortcuts]